# Custom Calendar view with setting event between two dates

Tags: android, calendar

I am creating application with calendar in which i have to show the events on particular dates. I have created a custom Calendar view and i have set events on dates as well. But problem is that there are two types of data in which one is for event for one day(which i have done) and other is event between dates(which is little tricky).

I have option of adding event fromDate - toDate in Map(in loop) but that will take more time at runtime.
Is there any suggestion or solution for this problem or is there any library which handles this type of situations.

Comment: Check This library [Material Calender](https://github.com/prolificinteractive/material-calendarview)

Comment: @AbhishekSingh Will this also deal with FromDate -toDate event schedule ?

Comment: It will allow multiple range selection and also provide you decoration for different dates so you use it for events